# How can I make a method take a null value?

Tags: java, null, method-signature

If you have two overloaded methods like so:

```
public void methodName(File file){}
public void methodName(String string){}
```

If you try to call `methodName` with `null` you will get an error saying that it's ambiguous which is understandable because it doesn't know which method to do.

I know that you can just cast the null: `methodName((String) null)` but how can I create a method specifically to handle the situations where you call `methodName(null)`?

Something like this:

```
public void methodName(null null){}
```

How can I make a method which must take a null?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you've seen, the compiler can't resolve two methods that take different kinds of objects when you pass `null`.

The only way around this is either typecast, like you have done, or to have a method that takes a generic `Object` type and attempts to downcast:

```
public void methodName( Object object ) {
    if ( object == null ) {
        // do something with null
    } else if ( object instanceof File ) {
        // do something with ((File)object)
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Writing code that looks like this tends to be viewed as smelly, and for good reason.  It gets complicated quickly, is difficult to maintain, etc.  Your best bet is to typecast or to change your method signatures so that you (and the compiler) always know which function should be called to handle a specific `null` object.

Comment: Overloaded method with typed parameters ensure (and document) that only valid types are given.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is functionally correct code, and it actually answers the question that was asked.  I *did* point out directly that as a programming practice it is frowned upon and gave reasons for that.

Comment: @Andreas, the question is about how to write a function that can take `null` and resolve compiler ambiguities, it is *not* a question about the merits of typed parameters.

Comment: No the question was "How can I make a method which **must** take a null?". Eran has answer that perfectly. Your code doesn't answer the question, but does suggest a bad pattern (as you stated yourself). Hence the down vote ("answer is not useful").

Comment: The initial question is "how can I create a method specifically to handle the situations where you call methodName(null)?" and this is how you do that. Eran's answer doesn't actually answer that.  There are situations where downcasting is useful (as it turns out), so this is a technique worth knowing.  I respect your right to downvote however, bang on.

Answer (score 4):

Just make a method without any parameters.

```
public void methodName(){}
```

Requiring a method that `must take a null` is the same as requiring a method that always takes 5 or a method that always takes "foo". If the passed argument should always contain the same value, there's no need for that argument at all.

And if you were asking for a method that will be chosen whenever the passed argument is null, regardless of its type (i.e. both method calls below would call the same overloaded method),

```
File f = null;
String s = null;
methodName (f);
methodName (s);
```

that's not possible, since the overloaded method to be used must be chosen in compile time using the compile time types of the arguments. At compile time the compiler can't know that the passed variable with contain null when the method is executed.

Comment: The implementation of `methodName(File)` and `methodName(String)` can of course each do a null check and call `methodName()` if the parameter is null, ensuring that your two examples end up in the parameter-less overload you defined.

Comment: @Andreas And if all these methods are not `final`, it's important to document the internal calls.

Comment: Doesn't really answer OP's question.  He wants to have a generic `null` handler, and the only way to implement that is with a function that takes `Object` and tests for `null` or downcasts.  It *can* be done in Java.

Comment: @par ooh I like that one

Answer (score 3):

There is a type which is often used to represent a `null` and this is `Void` where the only valid value is `null`.

You can write

```
void methodName(Void v);
```

Where it is typically used is for generic return types like.

```
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws IOException {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            doSomething(fis);
        }
        return null;
    }
});

// later
future.get();
```

You might wonder, why not use `Runnable` as we would not need `return null;`, however `Runnable` cannot throw  a checked exception, so we much use Callable if we expect to capture the IOException in the `future` object.

In Java 8, you can use lambdas but the compiler will still expect to return a null if you throw a checked exception as it works out you have to be using Callable

```
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
            doSomething(fis);
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite understanding, can I not do `methodName(void null)` ? That seems perfect

Comment: @Aequitas You can do `methodName((Void) null);` as you still need a cast for overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

An argument passed can *always* always be null *if it is an `Object`*. It is when you try running a method on a null reference that you get a null pointer exception.

So, `public void methodName(File file){}` could be called as `methodName(null)` without an exception.

However,

```
public void methodName(File file) {
    file.delete();
}
```

will result in a null pointer exception if null is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a method that specifically takes `null`.  You'd have to do something like this:

```
methodName(File file) {
   if(file == null) {
      someOtherMethod();
   }
   else {
      // other stuff
   }
}
```

But it would be more common to just have `methodName(File)` handle `null`, and document what it does with `null`.  If you have it call another method and `methodName(File)` and `someOtherMethod()` are not both final, you should document the internal call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Remember that you may have implicit `null`. For example:

```
File file = null;
methodName(file);
```

However, Java compiler must link the call to the specific method signature, so it should know in compile time whether the `null` was passed.

On the other hand why stick to `null`? Nothing stops you to define the special type:

```
enum Null { NULL }
public void methodName(File file){}
public void methodName(String string){}
public void methodName(Null n) {}

methodName(Null.NULL); // or methodName(NULL); with import static
```