# Most specific constructor signature

Tags: java, methods, parameters, null, signature

Given constructors:

1. `A(B... params)`
2. `A(String param1, B... params)`

When I invoke `A(null)` first constructor is invoked. Is there a way of invoking second constructor with argument null, but without casting `null` to `String`?

EDIT:
I've made some mistakes describing my issues, now it should be ok.

Comment: What is the problem of calling `new A((String)null)`?

Comment: @kennytm I am not saying it is a problem, I am asking if there is another way of doing that.

Comment: Why are you looking for another way? What is wrong with this way and what's the issue you want to address? (Because there are no other ways, at least that I know of). And why do you have 2 constructors to begin with?

Comment: You could do `new A(null, new B[0]);` or `new A(null, null);` but that makes you already feel uncomfortable during writing.

Comment: Relevant, if not duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063904/how-can-i-make-a-method-take-a-null-value

Comment: @Tunaki It just doesn't seem too nice for me, but maybe it is just me. If there is not other way then whatever. This question can be deleted. Definition of this constructors are not mine.

Comment: The only way for a solid API would be to have a single constructor `A(String, B..)`. As the string is optional, can you not add a setter and just `A(B...)`?

Comment: @JoopEggen Unfortunately it's not my code.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you have

```
A a = new A(null);
```

That is the exactly so the only case where it goes wrong. (Assuming B is a concrete type, not generic.) You do not want

```
A a = new A((String)null);
A a = new A("");
```

Then go for the utmost, and add a shortcut constructor:

```
A() {
    this((String) null);
}

A a = new A();
```

*It does not prevent `new A(null)`.*

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, but I do not see your problem.

```
public class A
{
    A(String a)
    {
        System.out.println("constructor(String)");
    }

    A(String a, B... b)
    {
        System.out.println("constructor(String, B...)");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new A(null, null);
    }

    private static final class B
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer. What are you trying to answer here?

Comment: First: I do not like to get minus 1 from you only because you made a mistake in your question. Second: You only realized your mistake because of my anwer. Third: My answer has something new that you have missed: `new A(null, null)` does not need any cast. So this is an answer to use the second constructor without a cast.

Comment: It's not my downvote. No, I realized mistake earlier, because of comments, not your answer. Thirdly, `new A(null, null)` is not what I was looking for. I was asking about one argument solution.